# What should I do with my question if after a helpful answer question changes?

Tags: discussion

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45013840/6603342) regarding Botframework and C# but thanks to some help and guidance from a user it turns out to be something completely different to what I described in my original question.

I have edited the question with **Update mark** explaining what happens and the new exception that was raised.

My question is, would it be better to mark that question as solved and the user answer as the accepted one and give the credits to the user who help me bypass that issue and open a new one?

Comment: if scope of your problem changed dramatically. i believe you can accept the answer. but let them know you have follow up question by sharing link in comments area. At least that's what i would do

Comment: Thanks after giving it some though it makes sense to remain under the same question as the scope did not change that dramatically. Can you post this as an answer and i will mark it as correct.

Comment: It appears there's an answer already. Thanks though mate, glad to be help :)